# if relation R(A,B,C,D,E) with FDs {AC->B, AC->E, B->C}. What is highest normal form satisfied

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Here in FDs Attribute D is not included in any of FD so should we ignore it ? is there any rule which specifies that all attribute should be part of atleast on FDs?

As per my understanding this is looks 3NF.

Comment: You can't ignore `D`. It's not dependent on anything else so it has to be part of the candidate key.

Comment: Give a reference to the definitions and algorithm you are using. What does it say to do with D? Why do you think you have "understanding"? Why "looks"? Is that different than "is"?

Answer (score 1):

> Here in FDs Attribute D is not included in any of FD so should we ignore it ?

No, you can't. Simply it is not present in any non-trivial FD (it is in many trivial FDs, like D → D), and it *must* considered for the key, for example. In fact the (only) candidate keys of the relation are ABD and ACD.

The fact that the it is part of the key means for instance that the dependency AC → E violates the 3NF (since E is a not a prime attribute and AC is not a key), so the relation is not in 3NF.

A possible decomposition in 3NF can be found by applying the synthesis algorithm:

```
R1 <(A,B,C,E)>
R2 <(A,C,D)>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.